# Converting image from RGB to HSV color space

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, python-imaging-library

I couldn't find such function (i.e.  `RGB_to_HSV()`) in `Scipy` or `Matplotlib's` documentations, and Google doesn't show pointers, except `ActiveState` recipe which demonstrates `rgb2hsv` function, though not usable on `Numpy` array as is.

Does someone know of a shortcut?

---

Edit: Sorry, just found `matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv()` which is exactly what I was looking for. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Answering your own question is probably the way to go, rather than editing the answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Matplotlib provides RGB to HSV conversion function: [matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv()](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv):

> `matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr)`
>
> convert rgb values in a numpy array to hsv values input and output arrays should have shape (M,N,3)

Comment: yeah, need to wait 2 days to be able to accept, but won't forget ;)

Comment: in case you need it in the future, the [color module](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html) of scikit-image provides a lot of functions to convert from a color space to another.

Comment: I tried using the function and did not get any hue. on trying pylab.plot(hsv_to_rgb(rgb_to_hsv(my_image_rgb_values))), i get a black and white image. This means it is not calculating the hue for me.