# Efficient way to convert image stored as numpy array into hsv

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, parallel-processing

I'm doing some data analysis of images. For some analysis I would like to convert the image's pixels in to HSV from RGB in which they are originally stored.

At the moment I'm using this code:

```
def generate_hsv(im):
    coords = product(range(im.shape[0]), range(im.shape[1]))
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    m = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process_pixels)(im[i]) for i in coords)
    return np.array(m).reshape(im.shape)
```

Where `process_pixels` is just a wrapper for my conversion function:

```
def process_pixels(pixel):
    return rgb_to_hsv(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2])
```

The thing is it runs sluggishly.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or a better way to parallelize?

Comment: And how is `rgb_to_hsv` implemented? Also, is it working on one pixel at a time? If so, can't it process all pixels in one go? Did you try cv2's `rgb2hsv` func?

Comment: @Divakar It's from Python's colorsys. I'm having problems with installing cv2 so I haven't gotten around to trying it.

Comment: Share `rgb_to_hsv`'s implementation?

Comment: Before trying to parallelize the computation, try a conversion routine that can handle numpy arrays.  See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278323/converting-image-from-rgb-to-hsv-color-space

Comment: @Divakar: `rgb_to_hsv` is from the the python standard library `colorsys`.  See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/colorsys.py#L124

Comment: Totally misleading title and content. Your title talks about "converting numpy array into hsv" and then your content is about parallelization. Please fix this.

Answer (score 4):

`Colorsys` module has its implementation for each pixel with the input being expected as `(R,G,B)`. Now, [`colorsys`'s implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/colorsys.py#L124) is listed below -

```
def rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b):
    maxc = max(r, g, b)
    minc = min(r, g, b)
    v = maxc
    if minc == maxc:
        return 0.0, 0.0, v
    s = (maxc-minc) / maxc
    rc = (maxc-r) / (maxc-minc)
    gc = (maxc-g) / (maxc-minc)
    bc = (maxc-b) / (maxc-minc)
    if r == maxc:
        h = bc-gc
    elif g == maxc:
        h = 2.0+rc-bc
    else:
        h = 4.0+gc-rc
    h = (h/6.0) % 1.0
    return h, s, v
```

I have gone in with the assumption that the image being read is in `(B,G,R)` format, as is done with OpenCV's `cv2.imread`. So, let's vectorize the above mentioned function so that we could work with all pixels in a vectorized fashion. For vectorization, the usually preferred method is with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). So, with it, a vectorized implementation of `rgb_to_hsv` would look something like this (please notice how corresponding parts from the loopy code are transferred here) -

```
def rgb_to_hsv_vectorized(img): # img with BGR format
    maxc = img.max(-1)
    minc = img.min(-1)

    out = np.zeros(img.shape)
    out[:,:,2] = maxc
    out[:,:,1] = (maxc-minc) / maxc

    divs = (maxc[...,None] - img)/ ((maxc-minc)[...,None])
    cond1 = divs[...,0] - divs[...,1]
    cond2 = 2.0 + divs[...,2] - divs[...,0]
    h = 4.0 + divs[...,1] - divs[...,2]
    h[img[...,2]==maxc] = cond1[img[...,2]==maxc]
    h[img[...,1]==maxc] = cond2[img[...,1]==maxc]
    out[:,:,0] = (h/6.0) % 1.0

    out[minc == maxc,:2] = 0
    return out
```

**Runtime test**

Let's time it for a standard RGB image of size `(256,256)` and to create that let's use random numbers in `[0,255]`.

Here's a typical way to use colorsys's `rgb_to_hsv` on an image of pixels :

```
def rgb_to_hsv_loopy(img): 
    out_loopy = np.zeros(img.shape)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):   
            out_loopy[i,j] = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(img[i,j,2],img[i,j,1],img[i,j,0])
    return out_loopy
```

As alternatives, there are also `matplotlib's` and `OpenCV's` color converion versions, but they seem to produce different results. For the sake of timings, let's include them anyway.

```
In [69]: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(256,256,3)).astype('uint8')

In [70]: %timeit rgb_to_hsv_loopy(img)
1 loops, best of 3: 987 ms per loop

In [71]: %timeit matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(img)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.7 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

In [73]: %timeit rgb_to_hsv_vectorized(img)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop

In [74]: np.allclose(rgb_to_hsv_vectorized(img),rgb_to_hsv_loopy(img))
Out[74]: True   # Making sure vectorized version replicates intended behavior
```

Comment: :7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  out[:,:,2] = (maxc-minc) / maxc
:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  divs = (maxc[...,None] - img)/ ((maxc-minc)[...,None])
:15: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in remainder
  out[:,:,0] = (h/6.0) % 1.0

Answer (score 3):

As Warren Weckesser said, the conversion function is problematic. I ended up using matplotlib:

`matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr)`

It now runs a million times faster.

Comment: Does it produce similar if not same results as with colorsys's RGB2HSV conversion?